# Setting configuration while maintaining JPanel type

Tags: java, swing, oop, applet, jpanel

I try to run the following source but get

> Type mismatch: cannot convert from CustomJPan to JPanel

errors.  Can someone please help?  Please excuse the source, I did it off the top of my head.

```
public class rebuiltgui extends JApplet {

  public void init() {

    JPanel jpan = new CustomJPan();     
  }
}

class CustomJPan  {

  public JPanel CustomJPan()  {

    thispan = new JPanel();
    thispan.setBackground( Color.red );
    return thispan;
  }

  public changeColour() {

    // Change colour to blue here
  }
}
```

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classes.html

Comment: Sorry I thought I was subclassing (facepalm)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like

```
public class rebuiltgui extends JApplet {

  public void init() {

    JPanel jpan = new CustomJPan();     
  }
}

class CustomJPan extends  JPanel {

  public CustomJPan()  {
      super();
      setBackground( Color.red );
  }

  public void changeColour() {

    // Change colour to blue here
  }
}
```

I have changed to extend jpanel

Comment: Great! It Works! I was out of options online.  This was really bothering me. TYVM

Comment: You are the greatest my friend

Answer (score 2):

Your code does not do direct subclassing since CustomJPan extends nothing.  Instead you seem to have a "pseudo" constructor that has the same name as the class, CustomJPan, tries to return something, and you know of course that constructors are declared to return nothing.

If you want to subclass, you must *extend* another class.

i.e.,

```
public class CustomJPan extends JPanel {

   // a real constructor has no return type!
   public CustomJPan() {
       // ....         
   }

  // ... etc
}
```

Subclassing is well covered in any introductory Java textbook, and you would do well to read the chapter on this.

A caveat: you will want to avoid subclassing unless you have a definite need such as the desire to change the innate behavior of a class, especially when you wish to override methods.

Comment: Sorry! I"m a C++  guy and OOPing Swing is a little new

Comment: @RolandSams: Again, you will want to read the text on this as it's all well explained there.

Comment: I just want a neat way to clean the debris from my main Java file. (like setting component properties) I thought hiding the various JPanels and such in other classes

Comment: btw: these JPanels will contain other components

Comment: @RolandSams: sometimes its cleaner to create a simple factory method to do this.